# Errors in standalone mode : permission denied

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

While running code in standalone mode,

```
laxmikant@laxmikant-Inspiron-1464:~/Work/hadoop-0.21.0$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-mapred examples-0.21.0.jar grep input output '[a-z.]+'

bash: /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: Permission denied
bash: /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: Permission denied`
```

What is to be done to remove this errors? I have set java_home & path correctly.
I tried to search on net, but couldn't find it. Can you please send the commands needed to allocate permissions & exact steps?

Answer (score 0):

go to `/home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/` folder and execute the command:

```
$ ls -lh | grep java
```

and see if java has execution permissions. If not, run the command:

```
$ chmod +x java
```

Comment: it gave the result:                                                     --wx--x--x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 7.5K Jun  4  2012 java
-rwx--x--x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 7.7K Jun  4  2012 javac
-rwx--x--x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 7.7K Jun  4  2012 javadoc
-rwx--x--x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 7.7K Jun  4  2012 javah s
-rwx--x--x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 7.7K Jun  4  2012 javap
-rwx--x--x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 1.8K Jun  4  2012 java-rmi.cgi
-rwx--x--x 1 laxmikant laxmikant  96K Jun  4  2012 javaws            still not working...

Comment: I see you're not executing java binary directly. But, instead, hadoop. Maybe you need read permissions on java. Change the chmod command to "$ chmod +r java".

Comment: now i got this:                                                        bin/hadoop: line 120: /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
bin/hadoop: line 120: /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: Success

Comment: And what are your permissions for "bin/hadoop"?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 4.1K Aug 17  2010 hadoop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 8.5K Aug 17  2010 hadoop-config.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 3.8K Aug 17  2010 hadoop-daemon.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 laxmikant laxmikant 1.3K Aug 17  2010 hadoop-daemons.sh

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar with hadoop. Maybe it is a process you are forgeting to start or something. Hope you find your answer.